Uiautomation Disconnected error when automating user profile switch case
I am using latest uiautomator to write simple test on noughat. The case involves switching from adult to child profile and verifying if launcher is loaded. As soon as adult to child profile or child to adult profile is switched, illegalstateexeception: Uiautomation not connected! error is thrown. What could be the issue
